# Manipulating shapefile into PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, shapefile, google-maps-api

I have a series of shape files that I am trying to convert and enter into a postgis database so that I can pull the data out as GeoJSON but I am having troubles getting the data to enter with the correct coordinate values.

My source files say they are:

```
Datum:  NAD 83, CSRS98
Projection: UTM Extended Zone 13
```

And when I run `gdalsrsinfo` against the `.prj` file, I get the following:

```
PROJ.4 : '+proj=utm +zone=13 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs '

OGC WKT :
PROJCS["NAD_1983_CSRS98_UTM_Zone_13N",
GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983_CSRS98",
    DATUM["NAD83_Canadian_Spatial_Reference_System",
        SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
    UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],
PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-105.0],
PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],
    UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

Using that information, I pulled up http://georepository.com/crs_4140/NAD83-CSRS98.html and see the ID is listed at `4140`.

So I ran

```
shp2pgsql -s 4140 shapefile > output.sql
```

But when I import the result into postgis, my coordinates are all out of sorts:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) FROM shapefile_import;
{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[535472.058,5466281.22],[535069.83,5466278.55],[535068.17,5466514.07],[535068.03,5466534.18],[535066.992,5466680.332],[535064.14,5467082.11],[535061.3,5467483.903],[535058.46,5467885.69],[535460.67,5467887.69],[535862.87,5467889.69],[536265.07,5467891.69],[536667.28,5467893.69],[536669.945,5467492.576],[536672.61,5467091.46],[536675.278,5466690.345],[536677.54,5466350.32],[536677.81,5466310.46],[536677.95,5466289.23],[536276.118,5466286.56],[535874.28,5466283.89],[535472.058,5466281.22]]]]}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I have been using http://geojsonlint.com to validate.

**Edit 1**

JGH's answer is correct, I was using the wrong ID in my conversion.  It should have been `2151`.

I ran now run `SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(geom,4326)) FROM shapefile_import;`

Comment: what do you mean "out of sorts" those look like plausible UTM coordinates to me

Comment: As documented AsGeoJSON http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html creates old-school GeoJSON that supports different coordinate systems http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html. You can validate such GeoJSON in another site http://geojson.io. However, your GeoJSON is missing the crs member and can't be reprojected right.

Comment: @user30184 is there a way to output an the "new" format in that case?  I am looking to overlay these onto Google Maps API with `addGeoJson` which requires the inclusion of a `Feature` or `FeatureCollection`

Comment: It should be close to enough if you translate into epsg:4326 and omit crs member.

Comment: Correction: geojson.io can't be used for validating old school geojson. I have not found any site yet that does that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SRID `4140` is the wrong one, as it is in lat-long:

```
+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs
```

The SRID for the UTM zone you are looking for is [`2151`](https://epsg.io/2151):

```
+proj=utm +zone=13 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

Comment: Aha, that makes sense.  I am now able to perform a `ST_AsGeonJSON(ST_Transform(geom, 4326))` to get my lnglat values.

Comment: @user30184 correct, typo.

Answer (score 1):

Geojson linter uses wgs84 (EPSG:4326) wystem. Your is in 4140.

```
The coordinate reference system for all GeoJSON coordinates is a
geographic coordinate reference system, using the World Geodetic
System 1984 (WGS 84) [WGS84] datum, with longitude and latitude units
of decimal degrees.
```

Your query should be

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(geom,4326)) FROM shapefile_import;
```